# How to correct spelling errors in a LUIS.AI application from user utterances? Use the Bing spellchecker api or label misspelled words in intents

Tags: botframework, spell-checking, azure-language-understanding

An article here gave some caution to using the Bing spellchecker api for washing all of your user utterances into your bot channel.

[Link to article here](https://stephaneeyskens.wordpress.com/2017/05/08/think-twice-before-enabling-bing-spell-check-at-luis-level/)

Point being the entity could become unravled when the spellchecker is turned on?  So if you have an obscure word style entity starblazingIT this might be reconstructed to star blazing IT.  Thus harming the entity.

With that said the article was written in 2016 so perhaps this concern has been addressed but I can't find any documentation on it.

The documentation I did find on it gave an outlet for ignoring spelling mistakes and simply label utterances and the LUIS would learn proper spelling as well as typos... That is a loaded statement.  What does that mean exactly and is luis really learning proper spelling or just adding the bad spellings in there as an alternative answer?

Because if that is the case then one would have to watch misspelled utterances and add in variations all of the time. Or would Luis overtime training learn that a particular word can have variations and be misspelled and to add that in with the correct intent model of utterances?

Here is a [link to the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-bing-spellcheck) and quote below:

> Ignore spelling mistakes
>   If you don't want to use the Bing Spell Check API v7 service, you can label utterances that have spelling mistakes so that LUIS can learn proper spelling as well as typos. This option requires more labeling effort than using a spell checker.

Overall what is the best practice of word misspelling correction for your luis chatbot application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no right answer here, but you have to do one or the other. LUIS does not handle typos well without training. For example, "I want to look up my order" gets 99.7% confidence on my viewOrder intent but "I want to look up my odrer" is only 36.4%, below my threshold for intent recognition. Spell check catches and fixes this. You could have almost endless varieties of typos across all intents. So while it's not that hard to label new utterances (and you should be doing this to improve your model anyway), it will be a continuous effort.

I did some testing just now and the spell check appears to be more tolerant of mashups, industry-specific terms, and software names. For example, it no longer splits SmartIT as mentioned in the article you linked. But I would definitely recommend testing with you entity names and ensure it's not going to "correct" words you don't want corrected.

My suggestion is to use Bing and, if needed, modify your entity identification (in example article, could just recognize both SmartIT and Smart IT as entities).

Comment: ahh I see what you're saying. also, i know with the qna knowledge base you can you utilize word alterations for synonyms too which I am assuming would help with that as well. I guess per se.  thanks for the answer